# Map function across multi-column DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Given a `DataFrame` like the following

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'y': [4, 3, 2, 1]})
```

I would like to map a row-wise function across its columns

```
In [3]: df.map(lambda (x, y): x + y)
```

and get something like the following

```
0    5
1    5
2    5
3    5
Name: None, dtype: int64
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Is this really what you want to do? Ideally you want to avoid using `apply` if there is a vectorised method, so just `df['x'] + df['y']` would work

Comment: I'm aware.  My actual job is significantly more complex.  This is here just for simplicity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply a function row-wise by setting `axis=1`

```
df.apply(lambda row: row.x + row.y, axis=1)

Out[145]: 
0    5
1    5
2    5
3    5
dtype: int64
```